# In good OOP principle, should a nodeView ask to be added to a tree, or should a tree add the nodeView?

Tags: ios, oop, design-patterns

I wonder what is a good OOP principle, if in an iOS app, there is a `UITreeView`, and a `UINodeView`, with the `UITreeView` object having a `rootNodeView`, and this root node branches off with `leftChildNodeView`, and `rightChildNodeView`.

If each `UINodeView` object can be "dragged and dropped" any where in the screen, which is implemented in `UINodeView`'s `-touchesMoved` handler -- is that good OOP principle?  In addition, if a new nodeView `foo` is really close to one of the nodes that has no left or right child, the node `foo` can be added to that node as a child.

And I suppose if another nodeView that is `bar` and also has no parents (that is, also dangling), it makes sense that `foo` can be added as `bar`'s child as well.

Should this `foo` nodeView "ask for permission from a node to be added as a left or right child" and "add it if allowed", or should the `UIViewController` or `UITreeView` detects that a node is moving inside itself, and "decide that it is close to another node (of all the nodes on screen) and has no left or right child, and add `foo` as a child"?

Obviously if only a node in the tree can add a child node, then the `UITreeView` can do the job, but if any node (dangling or not) can be a parent, then `UIViewController` or the main view `UIView` seems to need to do the job.

Does doing it one way or the other violate good OOP principles?

Comment: Could you post some code? Like the one that will handle those changes, controller and view.

Answer (score 1):

I´d say the UITreeView should handle this and the Nodes should inform him via protocol/delegate-communication about position changes. The TreeView is the only object that can check, if a position change of a node results in collisioning with another node etc.

If you want to write real good OOP-code, try using a "Model-View-Controller"-pattern, where your View is your TreeView, your Model should hold all Node-Data-Objects and provide some methods for collision detection between the nodes, and your Controller should receive the position changes from your view, talk to the model, decide what to do and then take the apprioate actions (like adding a node as a leaf of another node).

That way you´re fully flexible for future changes, like using a database instead of RAM for data storage, or using the code for iPad instead of iPhone just by replacing the View.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with stk, there needs to be a clear distinction between the Model, that is the implementation of the business rules, and the View(s), that are the visual representation.

The revealing paragraph is the last one:

> Obviously if only a node in the tree can add a child node, then the
>   UITreeView can do the job, but if any node (dangling or not) can be a
>   parent, then UIViewController or the main view UIView seems to need to
>   do the job.

In other words your Model depends upon the business rules. You need to design the logic so that you can express the rules. If you have free floating nodes, then clearly they must hold the attachment logic.

So separate the Tree/Node logic from the View logic.